# SQL Server converting string to datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime, substring, converters

I'm using SQL server and I need to convert a piece of string to datetime but I'm getting the error

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

This is my code so far that is causing the issue

```
SELECT TOP (1) [stream]
    , convert(datetime, SUBSTRING(Stream, 12, 10), 103) as Date
FROM x
where .....

select *
from
```

When I change the datetime to varchar the date comes out as "03/28/2021"

However I need it to come out as "28/03/2021" to get it to work I believe

Essentially just switching the month and date I believe?

Any ideas?

Comment: In what exact format are dates in incoming stream?

Comment: [Set dateformat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: hi all, the data is streaming in as 03/28/2021 . so thats why i showed it as a varchar as the default value, i need to change it to 28/03/2021

Comment: @d_chawke what does `Stream` contain? If parsing fails, it's because the date *string* doesn't match the style. Dates themselves have no format, they're binary values. If `CONVERT` succeeds, the result will have no format. It's up to the client to display the `datetime` value one way or another

Comment: Don't use `varchar`s for date and time values in the first place. There are 6 date and time data types to choose from which are vastly better. Date and time data types don't have a format either, it's up to the presentation to choose what format they appear in, *not* the RDBMS.

Comment: No one can debug fragments of sql statements that use data that cannot be seen. The most likely explanation is that your assumption about the format of EVERY substring in your table is incorrect - a common problem with using strings that have multiple embedded "columns" in them. Another common problem is assuming a particular part of your query is the source of the problem when a different part is a factor. Use the try_convert suggestion to validate your format assumption first. And note that you obviously have a date and not a datetime value - so why convert to datetime?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information here to give you an exact answer - we don't know exactly what intput data you're feeding it.

The documentation for converting to DateTime :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

has locale codes (where you're passing 103) for various datetime formats dd/mm/yyy , mm/dd/yyyy etc

find the one that applies to what you're trying to do.

Your error about an "out of range value" means you're using the wrong locale format - and a DAY value of over 12 (eg, 28th) is being interpreted as the MONTH value. As there isn't a 28th month in the calendar it throws an error.

you're passing in a locale code of 103 = which is british english : dd/mm/yyyy
Try replacing that with 101 (en-US) for mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: Hi @JimP76, yes i have to use 103 local code. however its not converting it for me, the data is coming in as "03/28/2021". but i need to swap the day and month. i thought by putting in datetime and 103 code it would do it for me, but it doesn't seem to, hence the error

Comment: 03/28/20212 is not 103 friendly. You would need to change it to 101. 
103 is telling SQL to interpret it as the 3rd day of the 28th month, in British English dd/mm/yyyy format

Comment: @d_chawke in a long winded way, this answer is saying use 101 **NOT** 103 :) you re trying to convert it to a date, so set the style to the format it is in now, and after that you have a native date which does not have a format.

Comment: fantastic! thank you both, that works great, sorry i am a newbie at this but this is great learning for me. thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

You need to tell SQL Server what the incoming date format is.

Issue `set dateformat mdy` and then execute your query.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. Dateformat is often a cause of datetime errors. I'm sorry this answer caused you problems.

Comment: It wasn't the OP, when the question is specifically using convert + style then it doesn't matter what the default date format is because the format is specified. Therefore this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `try_convert` to debug. It will show null instead of errors:

```
SELECT TOP (1) [stream]
    , convert(datetime, SUBSTRING(Stream, 12, 10), 103) as Date
FROM x
where try_convert(datetime, SUBSTRING(Stream, 12, 10), 103)
  is null
```